# Volume of a solid in region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a problem:
"Find the volume of the region bounded by the paraboloid $ z= x^2 + y^2$ and the plane $x + y = 1$ in the first octant.

I drew a picture, [image]

From that image, I got
$\int _0^1\int _0^{1-y}\:x^2+y^2dydx$

But I think that's wrong. Could someone walk me through the process of doing this or at least setting up the integral? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set over which we'll be integrating can be written as
$$M=\{0 \leq x \leq 1\textrm{ and }0 \leq y \leq 1-x\}$$
*(you could replace $\leq$ by $<$ - it doesn't matter since we're interested in integrating over subsets and not single points)*

We can find the volume of the region bounded by noting that $x^2+y^2 \geq 0$ and therefore the paraboloid will be our *upper* bound:

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int^{1-x}_0 x^2+y^2 dy\right)dx=\int_0^1yx^2+\frac{y^3}{3} \Big|_0^{1-x}=\int_0^1 (1-x)x^2+\frac{(1-x)^3}{3}dx=\frac{1}{6}.$$

**Alternative:** Note that we also may write integration set as
$$M'=\{0 \leq y \leq 1\textrm{ and }0 \leq x \leq 1-y\}$$
which would result in
$$\int_0^1 \left(\int^{1-y}_0 x^2+y^2 dx\right)dy$$

Make sure you understand how constructing $M$ works - one variable is bounded by constants and the other by a function (it can be done in at least 2 ways in 2-dimensional plane) and only then do we write the integral making sure that the functional constraint must be included in the most inner integral (in $\mathbb{R}^2)$.